# Can I access a PHP Class Constant using a variable for the constant name?

Tags: php, class-constants

When accessing a class constant I see that I can use a variable for the class name, e.g. `$classname::CONST_VALUE`.

What if I want to use a variable for the constant name, e.g. `self::$constant`. This does not seem to work.  Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$variable = $classname.'::'.$constant;

constant($variable);
```

See the docs: http://php.net/constant

Comment: I actually had the same problem earlier today and I googled it.